# SharePoint designer workflow failed to work for certain period of time

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

We had an issue with one of our workflow and it stopped working for sometime due to an error. for some reason we haven't noticed it.

is there any chance we can run the workflow for only entries made for that period of time lets say between 1/1/2018 to 3/1/2018.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the fatal error is. You can check the service status to see whether there was/is a problem with SharePoint.

Which actions are you using in the workflow and how many instances of the Workflow are actively running. A maximum of 15 workflows can run at the same time, naybe this can be the cause?

Comment: the error caused due to migration we haven't noticed it until its too late. users are already started using the custom list. The workflow is used to delete an entry from another list based on the certain conditions. Please see this link for more details.we have managed to solve the problem with the errors of the workflow. But since the workflow is not working the entry made had no effect. Is there any way we can run the workflow for certain period of time to the list items that didnt run the workflow.

Comment: @Rinu The workflow is started when an item is created (I suppose). Simply allow the workflow to be started manual, select the records (one by one, unfortunately) and attach and start the workflow manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable retention and create a retention stage in the information management policy settings in the list settings.

Go to list settings->Information management policy settings->click one content type->enable retention->add a retention stage->in the action, select “start a workflow”, select “repeat this stage’s action until the next stage is activated” and specify the day to repeat.

For more detailed information, you could refer to the articles below.

The article below is about how to create a timed Workflow in SharePoint 2010.

http://blogs.askcts.com/2013/05/14/creating-a-timed-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010/

Create and apply information management policies.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Retention Policy in SharePoint 2013.

https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score -1):

Add a condition at the start
if created greater than date1
   then if created less than date2
    //start the workflow actions